# Restart activity completely everytime particular activity is reached

Tags: android, android-activity

I have an `activity` with some very complicated third party logic that deals with videos and audio.

All these 3rd party setup have convoluted setups with different callbacks and server requests.

Now, from this `activity`, user have the ability to go away from it.

When user presses back, I wish my `activity` to resume as if it is just a new `activity` being launched. (So basically I rather all my 3rd party stuff to go through the whole life cycle, instead of doing resume logic which is a pain for me to maintain)

Is there a way for this particular `activity` to always restart? instead of just resume when it is navigated?

I suppose i could `finish()` my activity whenever i am going away from it, and when user goes back, explicitly launch it buy `startActivity()`;

But are there some other way? My activity only requires 1 Extra String for in bundle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During run time, activities are stacked so Activity A will remain in memory as long as Activity B, which was launched by Activity A, is alive.

You can call `finish()` for Activity A and launch Activity B from A's parent, and when B is being closed - relaunch A from the same parent, but that's just bad practice and distorting the way activities should be used. You can also use [`recreate()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#recreate%28%29) method, to create a clean instance of the activity, which would be better.

However, my opinion is that in general, the BP solution would be handling Activity A's lifecycle events and deal with your 3rd party lib using 3rd party-related class, MVP pattern, etc.

Comment: Recreate API is what i am go with now.